# php how to display file from binary data

Tags: php, web-services

I have function that run web-service and bring me binary file:

```
$params->xmlRequest = $paramsStr;

$result = $s->__call("SubmitXmlString",array($params));

$obj_pros = get_object_vars($result);
$xml =  $obj_pros['SubmitXmlStringResult']; 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 

return ($xml);
```

example for response:

```
<PnrGetReportDoc ReportName="ExternalDocument">
    <Report ID="6214" Type="pdf" Name="file name" IsCompressed="1">
        <![CDATA[JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAQolJU......................VPRg==]]>
        </Report>
    <ReportImages>
</ReportImages>
</PnrGetReportDoc>
```

I would like to ECHO the content in order to display the file

I tried to echo the binary but:
1. PDF isn't display

2. binary characters start without the opening notes: `<![CDATA[`

This is my php file where i'm trying to display the file:

```
header('Content-type: application/'pdf);
$fileData = get_file_data ($_GET['fileID']);

echo $fileData->Report;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is *not* binary. Precisely, XML is well known for being a *plain text* data format.

From the sample data you've shared I imagine it's [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), a popular algorithm to encode binary data as plain text. PHP has a [native function to decode it](https://php.net/base64_decode).